# this java code isn't functioning correctly

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, return, boolean

this is an array filter that returns 1 when the arguments are meet and 0 when they are not. for the arguments when 9 exists 11 must exist as well & when 7 exists in the array 13 must not exist.

my code returns 0 even though 9 and 11 exist and 7 exists but 13 doesn't exist. could someone please take a look at it?

```
public class Question4 {
    private int [] array = {1,2,3,4,9,11,7};
    private boolean condition1 = true;
    private boolean condition2 = true;
    
    public int isFilter() {
        //condition 1 : (if list contains 9 then it must contain 11)
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] == 9) {
                for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                    if (array[j] == 11) {
                        condition1 = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        condition1 = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        //condition 2 : (if list contains 7 then it must not contain 13)
        for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
            if (array[k] == 7) {
                for (int l = 0; l < array.length; l++) {
                    if (array[l] == 13) {
                        condition2 = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        condition2 = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        //Evaluation and Return
        if (condition1 == true && condition2 == true) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So... do you know how to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) a program?

Comment: @MarsAtomic no, I am a beginner at programming in general.

Comment: I found out that I needed break statements in order for this to work. Thank you all for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

Because this is homework, I’m going to answer broadly rather than with “code”.

Your main problem is your code is hard to read; your best first step is refactoring:

Create a method like this:

```
private static boolean contains(int[] array, int i) {
    // write your own implementation here that returns true if array contains i
}
```

The use it to rewrite your conditions, eg:

```
if (contains(array, 7) && contains(array, 13)) {
    // broken rule - do something
}
```

After doing that it should be easy to write and easy to read.

Comment: The class name gave it away huh, Thank you I'll be mindful of the way I write code next time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
private boolean condition1 = true;
private boolean condition2 = true;
```

Use

```
 private boolean condition1 = false;
 private boolean condition2 = false;
```

Comment: sorry, that didn't work for me